# Post request for an API-endpoint "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating an api-endpoint (using node.js) to post data to mysql db and receiving this error in postman:

> "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0".

I've done a similar function for a GET request with an example of the json data that will be posted to my endpoint, and that works as it should and is injected in the db (no need to show the whole function with queries as the error occurs in this small snippet). When doing the post request I get the error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here. I'd appreciate any feedback!! Cheers!

```
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        function callback(error, response, body) {
            let object = JSON.parse(body);
                let objectItems = object._items[0]

            });
            console.log(objectItems)
          }
     callback(req);
   })
```

Comment: this error usually means that you're getting back the default index.html, because you're request failed. When doing post or put requests, you need to include a header, i'd assume this is where you're error

Comment: thank you @rebecca!! this worked and I got further. Great! 
Now I ran into a new hurdle and we're getting a 404 error... I can't figure out why. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: well 404 suggests that the requested source isn't available. maybe you have a typo in your path or something similar?